# DynamicMethod call Instance method

Tags: c#, emit, dynamicmethod

If I create a DynamicMethod from inside a class method how can I call another method of my class from the DynamicMethod Delegate? I need somehow to capture the this reference in the DynamicMethod code. 
But I can't find an overladed version of ILGenerator.Emit which takes an object as parameter.

The code is so far:

```
    void CallOpc(string name, object[] inp, object[] outp)
    {
        //...
    }

    public D CreateDelegate<D>(string opcName) where D : class
    {
        var dType = typeof(D);
        var invoke = dType.GetMethod("Invoke");

        var parameters = invoke.GetParameters();
        var paramTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod(
            opcName,
            invoke.ReturnType,
            paramTypes,
            true);

        var inp = parameters.Where(p => !p.IsOut).Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToList();
        var outp = parameters.Where(p => p.IsOut).Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToList();
        if (invoke.ReturnType != typeof(void))
        {
            outp.Insert(0, invoke.ReturnType);
        }
        ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();

        LocalBuilder invar = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));
        LocalBuilder outvar = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, inp.Count);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, invar);

        for (int i = 0; i < inp.Count; i++)
        {
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, invar);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
            int j = Array.IndexOf(paramTypes, inp[i]);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, j);
            if (!inp[i].IsClass)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, inp[i]);
            }
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        }

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, outp.Count);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, outvar);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);   // <- push this on the evaluation stack ???
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, opcName);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, invar);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, outvar);
        MethodInfo callOpcMeth = GetType().GetMethod("CallOpc", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, callOpcMeth);


        for (int o = 0; o < outp.Count; o++)
        {
            // TODO: handle out params and return value
        }
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (D)(object)dm.CreateDelegate(dType);
    }
```

My problem is the line marked with ???

Comment: How can *code* have a reference to an object? it can't. You need to pass it as a parameter (at runtime).

Comment: Ok, I have a Communication Channel to a remote System which handles Method calls by 2 arrays of object; one for in and one for out values and the return value. For better type safety I want to provide delegates with the right signature. Therefore I'd like create dynamic delegates for diffrent method signatures. The delegate code will than create the 2 object[] arrays, puts the arguments in the one array, call the internal method and copies the return and out parameters out of the other array and returns.

Comment: Since we don't know the issue behind the scenes you're trying to fix or provide a solution I'll just add here a comment: who knows if using expression trees the same issue could be solved without using reflection emit directly..

Comment: Have added the complete code now.

Comment: Can't you use expression trees? They support this right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to reference the `this` pointer from a `DynamicMethod`?

At low level, methods do not have a specific `this` pointer, instead the first argument of the method is used as `this`.

To reference the `this` pointer, here is what you have to do:

- Prepend a new argument to your argument list, matching the type you want to use as `this`
- Use that argument as `this` wherever you want
- Create the delegate using [`DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type,Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z43fsh67(v=vs.110).aspx) to bind the first parameter to your object: `return (D)(object)dm.CreateDelegate(dType, this);`

Note that creating dynamic methods is expensive. If you generate the same DynamicMethod for multiple instances, you should cache the method itself, and create delegates using the cached method, but with different `target` parameter.

Comment: Thank you; now it works like intended. And yes I will cache the created delegates.